# Is google-api-python-client deprecating?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-python, google-python-api

Is `google-api-python-client` library going to hit the end of support soon ?

I have been using this library for many things & i am hitting multiple issues because the library is not thread-safe.

Should i work on using some wrapper class for having thread-safe ? Should i move to some other library that google-cloud provides, since this is neither thread-safe (causing lot of issues), nor long-lasting.

Comment: We can only speculate on if/when the library would hit end of support so this question is not really on topic here. Your best bet would be to contact the developers directly to see if they have any input.

Comment: Also, any inputs on the library being thread-unsafe ?

I am hitting bunch of issues & i suspect that those are coming because of library being not thread-safe...

If you want i can post the list of stacks i'm facing... (please note that - these stacks are coming only if i bombard lot of API requests continuously ) if i run a single API request, then no issues seen.

Comment: This might help you. It looks you are correct and the library is not thread-safe. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety

Answer (score 1):

It will not hit the end of support, any critical bugs will be fixed. But new features are not getting added and most the client library work is on [Google Cloud Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python).

Thread safety would be a feature request that won't get added to `google-api-python-client`. I would write your own wrappers that lock your usage of the library.

You can submit an issue on the `google-cloud-python` library and suggest thread safe methods, but it would help if you were clear about your specific use cases, since multithreading and asychronous feature can be complicated and use-case specific, so the easiest thing to do is just have users of the libraries do it themselves.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Could you elaborate what do you mean by 'users' ?
I'm using following code to connect to gcp resources.

compute = discovery.build( "compute", "v1", credentials=credentials)

Comment: and the case rather issue of thread-safe is because, if i fire say 5 createSnapshot methods in a single go, then it accepts few requests and drops few & sometimes list of issues come up that i mentioned in https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/447 request.

But no response there..